# Merge tag esql in embedded-sql

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, synonym-request

I think that [esql](/questions/tagged/esql) should be a synonym of [embedded-sql](/questions/tagged/embedded-sql). I know that there are much more questions about [esql](/questions/tagged/esql), but I think that [embedded-sql](/questions/tagged/embedded-sql) is much more meaningful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would rather use [entity-sql](/questions/tagged/entity-sql) for the questions where [esql](/questions/tagged/esql) is used as per meaning given to it by the tag wiki, and [embedded-sql](/questions/tagged/embedded-sql) for those questions about embedded SQL.

The current tag wiki for [esql](/questions/tagged/esql) says:

> Entity SQL is a storage-independent query language that is similar to SQL. Entity SQL allows you to query entity data, either as objects or in a tabular form.

Answer (score 0):

I would also say we should use [embedded-sql](/questions/tagged/embedded-sql) since it will be found by those searching on `embedded`.  It's way down on the list now, but with all the [esql](/questions/tagged/esql) questions added, it will move up and be found pretty quick by searchers.

Answer (score 0):

There are 31 questions (at this moment) tagged with [esql](/questions/tagged/esql) and [entity-framework](/questions/tagged/entity-framework), and according to the wiki of [esql](/questions/tagged/esql) I guess they are referring to [this particular Microsoft language](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387118.aspx) which is part of the .Net Framework.

I'm not an expert on [embedded-sql](/questions/tagged/embedded-sql) but [the Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedded_SQL) makes me think of something different (Since it lists the DBMS that implement embedded SQL) and the Microsoft version does not seem to use "embedded" anywhere in its description.

So, at least a clean-up is needed but at the moment I wouldn't agree with merging this tags.

Comment: Often are question wrong tagged. The entity framework has no direct relations to Entity SQL, however I think that a cleanup is needed but I read more often esql for embeded sql. A merge would avoid this errors.